# How to place items/ widgets inside other classes using tkinter and python oop

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I am struggling to figure out a way to add a coloured box beneath each button depending on which one is clicked.  Using tkinter and python3, i want to use classes to add a red box under button 1 if that was clicked, or a green box under button 2 if that was clicked.  I also want it to sit inside the respective frames that each button is housed in.  What are my options here?  Appreciate any support :)

```
import tkinter as tk

class MyDialog:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        top = self.top = tk.Toplevel(parent)
    self.myLabel = tk.Label(top, text='Enter Name')
        self.myLabel.pack()

        self.myEntryBox = tk.Entry(top)
        self.myEntryBox.pack()

        self.mySubmitButton = tk.Button(top, text='Press', command=self.send)
        self.mySubmitButton.pack()

    def send(self):
        global username
        username = self.myEntryBox.get()
        self.top.destroy()

def onClick():
    inputDialog = MyDialog(root)
    root.wait_window(inputDialog.top)
    print('Username: ', username)

class MainWindow:

    def __init__(self, master):

        mainLabel = tk.Label(root, text='Main Window')
        mainLabel.pack()

        button1_frame = tk.Frame()
        button1_frame.pack()

        mainButton = tk.Button(root, text='Button 1', command=onClick, width=20)
        mainButton.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        button_frame2 = tk.Frame()
        button_frame2.pack()

        mainButton2 = tk.Button(root, text='Button 2', command=onClick, width=20)
        mainButton2.pack(side=tk.LEFT)


root = tk.Tk()
app = MainWindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot about your question that is not clear, but hoping i understand what you want:

1. You want to indicate by colour which button is clicked.

You should bind an event to the button and use the config method to change the background color.

2. You want the buttons to sit inside the frames you created, not in the root window itself.

You have initialized the frame alright, but you did not set a parent for the frame, neither are you using the frame as the parent of the buttons.

So you might want to modify your code to be more like:

```
class MainWindow:

def __init__(self, master):

    mainLabel = tk.Label(root, text='Main Window')
    mainLabel.pack()

    button1_frame = tk.Frame(root)
    button1_frame.pack()

    mainButton = tk.Button(button1_frame, text='Button 1', command=onClick, width=20)
    mainButton.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: mainButton.config(bg='red'))
    mainButton.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

    button_frame2 = tk.Frame(root)
    button_frame2.pack()

    mainButton2 = tk.Button(button_frame2, text='Button 2', command=onClick, width=20)
    mainButton2.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: mainButton2.config(bg='green'))
    mainButton2.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
```